# How to add a new stream after avformat_write_header function is called?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming, libav, libavformat

I have several video sources that produce video frames. Each video source should be represented as the separate video stream inside an output video file(mp4 or mpegts).
The problem is that I should specify the exact number of streams and create them before `avformat_write_header` function is called. If I try to add the stream after, I will get crash inside `av_interleaved_write_frame`. Is any way to add a stream on the fly? Maybe there are some muxer options that I should specify? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, new streams can't be added after the header is written. libavformat checks if incoming packet for writing has a stream index outside of `[0,nb_streams-1]` and will fail if it does.

A MPEG-TS like container could be made to incorporate new streams, but ffmpeg doesn't support that.